# How to know if Geopoint is inside a Polygon with elasticsearch 7?

Tags: elasticsearch, geospatial

I've an index with Polygons of countries and what I want to do is to calculate given some coordinates, to witch country belongs.

I've tried in a lot of ways and I get always all my index as a result.
It is even posible to do that with elasticsearch?

This is my mapping (summarized to show only the interesting part for this question):

```
{
  properties: {
    geometry: { 'type': 'geo_shape' }
  }
}
```

This is the last query that I've tried:

```
{
  "query":{
     "bool":{
        "must":{
           "match_all":{

           }
        },
        "filter":{
           "geo_shape":{
              "geometry":{
                 "shape":{
                    "type":"point",
                    "coordinates":[
                       2.217779,
                       41.398349
                    ]
                 },
                 "relation":"intersects"
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

More information:

- My field `geometry` only can be Polygon or MultiPolygon
- All the points that I want to use to search after I have them in Geojson format (but of course I can transform it to any format if needed)

Comment: Can you show the query you're sending?

Comment: @Val question edited